# ASP.NET regular expression to restrict consecutive characters

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

Using ASP.NET syntax for the RegularExpressionValidator control, how do you specify restriction of two consecutive characters, say character 'x'?

Comment: This site is great for both learning regular expressions and it has a quick reference that you can refer to. Spend a couple of days going through the tutorial and you will be able to build regular expressions yourself, even if you know nothing about them when you start: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: Thanks for the RE link. I've bookmarked it and I plan on learning REs better. My problem is that I use REs so infrequently that I forget much of what I need to know in between uses. Then there's the different flavors to keep straight across the various languages and tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a regex like the following:

```
(\\w)\\1+
```

`(\\w)` will match any word character, and `\\1+` will match whatever character was matched with `(\\w)`.

I do not have access to asp.net at the moment, but take this console app as an example:

```
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("hello") ? "Not valid" : "Valid"); // Hello contains to consecutive l:s, hence not valid

Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("Bar") ? "Not valid" : "Valid"); // Bar does not contain any consecutive characters, so it's valid
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. I tried a RegularExpressionValidator with ValidationExpression="^([^x])\\1+$" and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Alexn is right, this is the way you match consecutive characters with a regex, i.e. `(a)\1` matches `aa`.

However, I think this is a case of everything looking like a nail when you're holding a hammer. I would not use regex to validate this input. Rather, I suggest validating this in code (just looping through the string, comparing `str[i]` and `str[i-1]`, checking for this condition).

Comment: OK, I know what to do in the code behind... It's now a mental challenge to figure out what to do with the ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator control. I still don't know what to assign to ValidationExpression. I tried ValidationExpression="^([^(x)]\1)$" and various other variations and I still don't have an RE that works to eliminate input with two consecutive values of 'x'.

Comment: I see. In my mind it's not worth the mental challenge (from a practical standpoint), as I believe regexes are not really meant to solve exactly this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^((?<char>\w)(?!\k<char>))*$
```

It matches `abc`, but not `abbc`.

**The key is to use so called "zero-width negative lookahead assertion" (syntax: (?! subexpression)).**

Here we make sure that a group matched with `(?<char>\w)` is not followed by itself (expressed with `(?!\k<char>)`).

Note that `\w` can be replaced with any valid set of characters (`\w` does not match white-spaces characters).

You can also do it without named group (note that the referenced group has number 2):

```
^((\w)(?!\2))*$
```

And its important to start with `^` and end with `$` to match the whole text.

If you want to only exclude text with consecutive `x` characters, you may use this

```
^((?<char>x)(?!\k<char>)|[^x\W])*$
```

or without backreferences

```
^(x(?!x)|[^x\W])*$
```

All syntax elements for *.NET Framework Regular Expressions* are explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to validate what's wrong as well as what's right of course. The regex `(.)\1` will match any two consecutive characters, so you can just reject any input that gives an IsValid result to that. If this is the only validation you need, I think this way is far easier than trying to come up with a regex to validate correct input instead.